# images gallery fancybox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have been trying but no luck with fancybox

In head I link the page to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
```

Here are my links to cdnjs

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Here are my code in JS

```
  $("a .fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });

$("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.jpeg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();
```

Here are my html

```
    <section class="col-1 first">
        <a class="fancybox" rel='gallery' href="images/my-office.jpg"><img src="images/my-office.jpg" /></a>

        <h3>My office</h3>
        <p>This is also called "The circle of neglect".</p>
    </section>

    <section class="col-1">
        <a class="fancybox" rel='gallery' href="images/my-cousin.jpg"><img src="images/my-cousin.jpg" alt="Eli Newton" title="Eli Newton" /></a>
        <h3>My dear cousin</h3>
        <p>My cousin is from Canada.</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: By "no luck" you mean that it will not work? Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you need to remove the space between the element and class since they are supposed to be referencing the same object. In other words, this

```
$("a .fancybox")
```

Should be

```
$("a.fancybox")
```

Cheers!